# Edit : Does hibernate supports storing geolocation? I am using postgres database

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, geolocation

I am using Postgres database, along with cube and earthdistance extensions.
Now, my query is there a defined way of querying database using hibernate or would have to be dependent on custom query. 
e.g. select s from Restaurant as s WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(88.474150, 27.046163), 1000) < ll_to_earth(s.latitude, s.longitude)

Comment: Hibernate should "support" everything which the underlying database, in this case MySQL, supports.  Can you expand on your question?  About what features in particular are you worried?

Comment: Сan you provide more information? Required to explain what is meant by phrase "storing geolocation".

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific datatype for storing geo locations in mysql. You can use float eg.72.152 for latitude and longitude or varchar() if using special character 10.152'